# Take variables from define function in python

Tags: python, variables, odeint

I have a question on extracting variables in def

For example,

```
def func(z,W):
    A = z[1]
    B = z[2]
    C = z[3]
    Var = k*B/C
    dAdW = A*3
    dBdW = B*2/Var
    dCdW = C**2*Var**2
    return dAdW, dBdW, dCdw
init = [0,0,1]
W = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
sol = odeint(func, init, W)
plt.plot(W,sol[:,0])
plt.plot(W,Var) # ----> this one
```

Since Var is not a differential equation,

I can't declare Var as Var = z[4]

I tried using global but it only yields the last value.

How do I get all the values of Var in an array so I can plot the Var?

k is a constant like 1

Thank you for taking a look into this!

Here is a full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

alpha = 0.0002
Uapb = 0.5
deltaH = -20000
Cpa = Cpb = 20
Cpi = 40
Ea = 25000
Kc1 = 100 # @ T=303
k1 = 0.004 #@ T=310K
CPcool = 20
Fao = 5
Cao = 1
mc = 1000
R = 1.987
To = 330


def func(z,W):
    pbar = z[0]
    X = z[1]
    Ta = z[2]
    T = z[3]
    k = k1*np.exp(Ea/R*(1/310-1/T))
    Kc = Kc1 * np.exp(deltaH / R * (1 / 303 - 1 / T))
    Ca = Cao * (1 - X) * To / T * pbar
    Cb = Cao*(1-X)*To/T*pbar
    Cc = 2*Cao*To/T*pbar
    Ci = To/T*pbar
    ra = k*(Ca*Cb-Cc**2/Kc)
    dxdw = -ra/Fao
    dpbardw = -alpha/(2*pbar)*T/To
    dTadw = (Uapb)*(T-Ta)/(mc*CPcool)
    dTdw = (Uapb*(Ta-T)+ra*deltaH)/(Fao*(Ca+Cb+Ci))
    return dxdw, dpbardw, dTadw, dTdw

init = [1, 0, 320, 320]
W = np.linspace(0,4500,1000)


sol = odeint(func, init, W)
#Xe = (2 * Kc - ((2 * Kc) ** 2 - 4 * Kc * (Kc - 4)) ** (1 / 2)) / (2 * (Kc - 4))
plt.plot(W, sol[:,0])
#plt.plot(W, Xe)
```

Comment: What is `k`, and why doesn't `func` use `W`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture the data from each call, you can do something like this:

```
capture_var = []

def func(z,W):
    Var = ...

    global capture_var
    capture_var.append(Var)
```

**Please note:** that this is rather a hack, and if you doing some basic scripting to solve some small problems is likely fine.  However, if you are working on a code base of any size, please don't do this sort of thing, as these sorts of practices can be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if this is not a good way to capture the data from def, how should I do it? Since Var contains variable that are declared inside def and those variables are changing as W changes, Var has to be calculated inside the def right? So what would be the best way do it? Btw Thank you so much for taking your time to read my dumb question :)

Comment: Look at the framework and see how they propose doing this.